# query to fetch x questions which have some tag y

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have 2 models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Tag(models.Model):
    Tag_id = models.IntegerField()
    ques_id = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

what will be query to get the 10 ques ids for the input tag ids? Output format should be:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "QUES 1",
"tags": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Abcd"
 }]
}
```

Comment: For given `tag` ids, or that just have a tag (perhaps multiple)?

Comment: for given tag "ids"

Comment: But here for a given tag, there can be *at most* one question, since there is a `ForeignKey` from `Tag` to `Question`.

Comment: Multiple tag ids can be assigned to a question

Comment: yes, but not multiple questions to a given `Tag`. It is a `Question 1-n Tag` relation.

Comment: i think i need to re create model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a given list of tag ids `tag_ids`, you can obtain the `Question`s with:

```
Question.objects.filter(tag__tag_id__in=tag_ids)
```

or you can limit the number of questions, and make these distinct with:

```
Question.objects.filter(tag__tag_id__in=tag_ids).distinct()[:10]
```

Some extra remarks:

> **Note**: Please make use of an [**`AutoField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField) for the primary key, this will ensure that the primary key is distributed accordingly, and furthermore that it is updated when you save your object.

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
>   will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
>   be `question`, instead of <s>`ques_id`</s>.